# Countdown Timer only counts down 1 second then stops

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

My countdown timer only counts down one second and then stops. I'm making a game that has a countdown clock and for ever incorrect answer, more time is added. I just can't get the timer to work.

```
var secondsLeft = document.getElementById("timer").textContent;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft = 120;
    secondsLeft--;
    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = secondsLeft;
}, 1000);
```

I think I may need to do create a for loop, but everything I've read says I can do this without one.
thanks!

Comment: you're resetting `secondLeft` to 120 in the function that runs every second. You need to move that line of code outside.

Comment: `secondsLeft = 120; secondsLeft--;` will cause `secondsLeft` to always be 119.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! :D

```js
var secondsLeft = 120;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft--;
    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = secondsLeft;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

You were resetting the `secondsLeft` back to 120 by having it inside the timer function.

Comment: @hannahatl, could you mark this answer as accepted if you think this is the best one?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting secondLeft in your function, if you have the time value inside of the #timer element. Then you can use the value it has by doing:

```
var secondsLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("timer").textContent);
```

you need to convert it first because textContent has the type of string which you can't use subtraction operator with.

So for the answer, you can use the following:

```
var secondsLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("timer").textContent);

var timer = setInterval(function () {
  secondsLeft--;
  document.getElementById("timer").textContent = secondsLeft;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: ahhh thank you so much!! I didn't even realize I did that. Much appreciated